# profanity filteration in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am servering some webdata to my site using apache `solr 4.10.3`. I have to block profanity.

How do I block profanity in search?

I have some confusion about this filter deployment also.

Should I apply filter for profanity at document indexing time or document search time?

Comment: Do you still want to be able to search for documents containing profanity and display them somewhere, or do you want to remove all words in a common wordlist? What are the rules for how you want to handle profanity? What have you tried?

Comment: I have to block these documents

Comment: So documents matching words from a wordlist shouldn't be indexed at all? How do you define what a profanity is? Can you just drop indexing the document from your indexing pipeline?

Comment: I have list of words that define profanity. I want if a document contains such words, it should not be indexed at all

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 possibilities :

1. Don't send the document to Solr in the first place (filter it in your code)
2. Implement a custom UpdateRequestProcessor : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors

Comment: Second possibility is at query time or index time ?

Comment: Index time : Every update request received by Solr is run through a chain of plugins known as Update Request Processor. This can be useful, for example, to add a field to the document being indexed or to change the value of a particular field or to drop an update if the incoming document doesn't fulfill certain criteria. In fact, a surprisingly large number of features in Solr are implemented as Update Processors and therefore it is necessary to understand how such plugins work and where are they configured.