# Solr blacklist word configuration to be indexed and stored

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search

I am using solr 6.2.1 and I want to omit all document having some blacklisted words(abusive words) in particular field on solr. I have the following text field configuration in schema.xml-

```xml
<!-- A text field that only splits on whitespace for exact matching of words -->
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Can anyone help me to omit blacklisted words to be indexed and stored on the Solr.

Guys, Is it possible? If yes, help me to correct the configuration.

Comment: You don't want to exclude just the words, you want to exclude the document completely? How are you indexing your documents?

Comment: If you want to drop the whole document upon abusive words ( do you? ) then I would go for an [Update Request Processor](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html).

Comment: Have a read here [profanity filteration in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435713/profanity-filteration-in-solr)

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you want to put a filter in front of your indexing pipeline. What you typically do to have something flexible in this case is:

1. you define your blacklisted in groups of related words, with some more metadata (like 'colors: black, white', 'cursing: fuck, bitch...')
2. on startup, you create a Lucene (not solr, you have to use the Lucene lower level api) Query per group of words
3. when you are going to insert a new doc, you first create a [MemoryIndex](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/memory/org/apache/lucene/index/memory/package-summary.html) containing the single doc, and you run it through all your blacklist queries, if any match, you skip the doc, don't index it.

In your simplest case you have just one group of words, but if you define it by groups etc it will be more flexible and easier to maintain the lists of words.